# Entity framework: unexpected cursor error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf, cursor

I am using Entity Framework 6 and SQL Server. I am writing some code in a WCF service for saving data when receives a POST http request.

I have done some methods and they work well as expected. But now I'm writing another method.. in debug mode it seems like other, but when I call the saveChanges method I get this:

```
{"A cursor with the name 'FldCursor1' does not exist.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

But I don't even know what is a cursor... of course I have searched in the web, but I don't know why there is this message. Further, the name **FldCursor1** isn't written in my code, I've searched it.

Do you know why this can happen?

I don't have used cursors anywhere... why this error?

If you need I can post some of my code, you have only to task. So, please let me know if you need code or if you have useful ideas for this problem.

**UPDATE**: when I get the error, I'm trying to add some new records in a table.

Comment: Please post the code related to this.  Sounds like the SQL being generated by EF is producing a cursor, which is horribly inefficient and I don't think I have ever seen that happen.

Comment: Yes, that seems strange behavior of EF here with the cursor. The code should make it clearer. Also you can try to log the actual SQL generated by following this guide at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [A cursor with the name 'cursor\_name' does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972022/a-cursor-with-the-name-cursor-name-does-not-exist)

Comment: Are you calling any stored procedures? Is your model called "Fld"?